# If an $n$-vertex graph does not contain $K_{2,t}$ then $|E|\le {1\over 2}(\sqrt{t-1}n^{3\over 2}+n)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

If an $n$-vertex graph does not contain $K_{2,t}$ then $|E|\le {1\over 2}(\sqrt{t-1}n^{3\over 2}+n)$ where $E$ is the set of edges and $K_{2,t}$ is a bipartite graph on between a set of $2$ vertices and a set of $t$ vertices. This question was solved for $t=2$ in the notes. I didn't quite understand what guaranteed the arguments for no argument was really explained with regards to the graph not containing $K_{2,2}$. I will write it down and if you could point out what relies on the absence of $K_{2,2}$ and it might give me a better perspective. A guidance about how to solve the question above is welcome even more.

$K_{2,2}:$

"Let us look at the number of trios $(x,y,z)$" such that $x$ is connected to $y$ and $z$ by edges." **Why do we look at this graph structure?** "Obviously, $\# \{(x,y,z)\}\le {n\choose 2}$.." I guess this does not depend on the graph not containing $K_{2,2}$. "Also, $\# \{(x,y,z)\}=\sum_{v\in E}{d(v)\choose 2}\ge n{{{\sum d(v)}\over n}\choose 2}$" And then an inequality is solved regularly... My questions are: Where does the absence of $K_{2,2}$ come into use **exactly**? How is it done with bigger $t$, following the same principle?

How can one arrive at the square root part? How can one get a quadratic expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you guess, the inequality
$$ \bigl|\{\,(x,y,z)\mid y< z, xy\in E, xz\in E\,\}\bigr|\le {n\choose 2}$$
*does* depend on the absence of $K_{2,2}$. For without this assumption we could only have estimates such as $\le{n\choose 3}$ or $\le{|E|\choose 2}$. But as we assume that there is no $K_{2,2}$, we know that for each of the $n\choose 2$ pairs $(y,z)$ with $y<z$ there can be at most one $x$ that give us a trio $(x,y,z)$: If there are two such trios $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y,z)$ then $x,x', y,z$ would form a $K_{2,2}$.

---

Regarding the case of $t>2$, my first try would be to consider $$\{\,(x,y_1,\ldots,y_t)\mid y_1<y_2<\ldots<y_t, xy_1\in E,\ldots, xy_t\in E\,\}$$
and observe that it has size $\le {n\choose t}$.

Comment: Thank you! It actually reduces the LHS with the factorials.

Comment: I wouldn't have observed it, as expressions such as "obviously" would always make me think this is the inactive part of the solution, not likely to include a condition. I wish it were(had been?) explained earlier.

Comment: @Meitar I agree - one is tempted to mix it up with one of the really obvious estimates $nchoose 3$ or $|E|\choose 2$. "By construction" or similar would distract less

Comment: Sorry for mistaking edges for vertices, by the way. I am not native.

Comment: Will you explain what $y_i<y_j$ means?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but do you have an idea as for how to translate these inequalities to a quadratic equation?